# D3 Selecting divs and Dynamicly Updating CSS classes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make an interactive calendar object that displays the past 5 days. It is comprised of html `<li>` and `<span>` elements. I realize that jquery might be the conventional way to solve dom manipulation, but I have motivation to use a d3 approach. The code is pretty clear itself, but I will also include a brief synopsis of what I'm trying to do afterwards.

```js
d3.selectAll('li').on('click', function(d) {
  var array = d3.select(this)[0];
  var tab = array[0];
  var tabClass = tab.className.split(" ")[1];
  var priorTab = d3.selectAll('.tab0');
  var tabIndex = [].indexOf.call(tab.parentNode.children, tab);
  priorTab.classed('tab0', false);
  d3.select(tab).classed(tabClass, false);
  d3.select(tab).classed('tab0', true);
  d3.selectAll('li:not(.tab0)').each(function() {
    var tempArray = d3.select(this)[0];
    var tempTab = tempArray[0];
    var tempTabClass = tempTab.className.split(" ")[1];
    var tempIndex = [].indexOf.call(tempTab.parentNode.children, tempTab);
    var tempIndexDifference = Math.abs(tabIndex-tempIndex);
    d3.select(tempTab).classed(('tab'+tempIndexDifference), true);
  });
});
```

```css
.tab0 {
  color:#77b4c9;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

.tab0 span:first-of-type {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  display:block;
}

.tab1 {
  background-color: #cbdeea;
  color: #fff;
}

.tab2 {
  background-color: #a6cdd9;
  color: #fff;
}

.tab3 {
  background-color: #77b4c9;
  color: #fff;
}

.tab4 {
  background-color: #519ab6;
  color: #fff;
}

.contentTitleSize {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.contentTitle {
    color: #000;
    height: 73px;
    margin-top: 27px;
    font-family: Play;
}

.contentTitle, .contentArea {
  display:inline-block;
}

.contentArea {
  height:320px;
  width:312px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subheading {
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    font-family: Play;
    color: #77b4c9;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.outerContainer {
  width:566px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 27px;
}

section {
  display:block;
}

*, :after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

*, :after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}


.tabPanel {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:160px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

li {
  display:list-item;
}

.listTabs {
    display:block;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Play;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2.5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.11);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2.5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.11);
}

.container {
    height:320px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:24px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto-Regular,serif;
    line-height: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}

.bottomButton {
  height: 61px;
  background-color: #327ca3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Play;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 61px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">
    <div class="outerContainer">
        <section class="container">
            <ul class="tabPanel">
                <li class="listTabs tab0" role="button">
                    <span>02</span>
                    <span>OCT</span>
                </li>
                <li class="listTabs tab1" role="button">
                    <span>01</span>
                    <span>OCT</span>
                </li>
                <li class="listTabs tab2" role="button">
                    <span>30</span>
                    <span>SEP</span>
                </li>
                <li class="listTabs tab3" role="button">
                    <span>29</span>
                    <span>SEP</span>
                </li>
                <li class="listTabs tab4" role="button">
                    <span>28</span>
                    <span>SEP</span>
                </li>
           </ul>
           <div class="contentArea">
               <a class="contentTitle contentTitleSize">Content Area</a>
               <div class="subheading">
                   <span>
                   <strong>First</strong>
                   "Second and Third"::after
                   </span>
                   <span>more info</span>
               </div>
               <div class="details">
                   <p>lots of details</p>
               </div>
        </section>
        <div>
            <div class="bottomButton">
            Click Me</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

1. The user clicks a tab which then gets assigned a class to show that it is the active tab (`.tab0` in my code)
2. I have 4 other classes ranging from `.tab1` all the way to `.tab4`. These classes have a different `background-color`. The naming scheme is based on how far the tabs are from the active tab. `.tab1` being adjacent (top or bottom) `.tab4` being far away.
3. I then select all other tabs and use `.each()` to apply a separate `background-color` for the tab based on its relational position to the active tab. This is achieved by giving it a new `.tabx` class. So for example, if you clicked on the third tab in the middle (which has a `[].indexOf.call(tab.parentNode.children, tab)` equal to 2, then the tab above it and below it would have the class `tab1` -- because the absolute value of 0-1 is 1.

Despite my careful attempts to revise it, I can't get it working. None of the tabs are updated with new colors and I can't understand why. Dev tools shows that the index is being correctly calculated each time.

**Question:** How do I get this dynamic color update to work? In other words, whichever tab the user clicks on will be white, and all the other tabs will update the `background-color` based on their relational position to the active tab.

**Clarification**

To clarify, it's not the same as swapping the styles from the old active tab to the new, what I mean is updating all `background-color`s of the tabs to a new value based on how far away they are from the new active tab. For example, the tabs directly on the top and bottom of the new active tab would be the closest, and thus they should get the class: `.tab1`. The tabs that are two tabs away would get `.tab2` and so on. Note the initial state has the first tab being the active tab, and as such there will only be 1 tab with class `.tab1` because there can't be any tabs above it.

Comment: Your snippet is not running. It should be `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">`, https instead of http. Besides that there is another problem somewhere.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado That is strange, I can't find what's the matter with it either, I'll keep looking.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are expecting https://plnkr.co/edit/O7jhDkIsvaWrnqyVmO0V?p=preview
if yes i ll post it as answer.

Comment: @Cyril That's much closer than me. The only thing missing is when the user clicks on a new tab, the tab directly above it and below it should have the class `.tab1`, as they are the closest/adjacent to the active tab. Likewise, the other tabs would have class `.tab2` or `.tab3` depending on how far away they are.

Comment: Currently i am swapping the styles.
Such that if `tab1 is selected` and you click on tab 3.
Then both divs styles are swapped. Are you hinting @ another algo if yes kindly update the info in the question.

Comment: @Cyril Oh I see how you did it now, yea, I suppose I didn't make that clear enough. I tried adding a separate section below the question to address that. Thanks for the chance to clarify.

Comment: Does this solve your problem https://plnkr.co/edit/O7jhDkIsvaWrnqyVmO0V?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your click logic like this.

```
//select all lis
d3.selectAll('li').on('click', function(d, i) {
  //select the dom with .tab0
  var old = d3.select(".tab0");
  //swap the class with the selected li
  var oldClass = d3.select(old).node().node().className;
  var newClass = d3.select(this).node().className;
  d3.select(this).node().className = oldClass;
  d3.select(old).node().node().className = newClass;
  //make all tabs in ascending order excluding the li with tab0.
  var index = 1;
  d3.selectAll(".listTabs").each(function(d, i){
    if (!d3.select(this).classed("tab0")){
      d3.select(this).node().className = "listTabs";
      d3.select(this).classed("tab" + index, true);
      index++;
    }
  })
});
```

working code below:

```js
//select all lis
d3.selectAll('li').on('click', function(d, i) {
  //select the dom with .tab0
  var old = d3.select(".tab0");
  //swap the class with the selected li
  var oldClass = d3.select(old).node().node().className;
  var newClass = d3.select(this).node().className;
  d3.select(this).node().className = oldClass;
  d3.select(old).node().node().className = newClass;
  //make all tabs in ascending order excluding the li with tab0.
  var index = 1;
  d3.selectAll(".listTabs").each(function(d, i){
    if (!d3.select(this).classed("tab0")){
      d3.select(this).node().className = "listTabs";
      d3.select(this).classed("tab" + index, true);
      index++;
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.tab0 {
  color:#77b4c9;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

.tab0 span:first-of-type {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  display:block;
}

.tab1 {
  background-color: #cbdeea;
  color: #fff;
}

.tab2 {
  background-color: #a6cdd9;
  color: #fff;
}

.tab3 {
  background-color: #77b4c9;
  color: #fff;
}

.tab4 {
  background-color: #519ab6;
  color: #fff;
}

.contentTitleSize {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.contentTitle {
    color: #000;
    height: 73px;
    margin-top: 27px;
    font-family: Play;
}

.contentTitle, .contentArea {
  display:inline-block;
}

.contentArea {
  height:320px;
  width:312px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subheading {
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    font-family: Play;
    color: #77b4c9;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.outerContainer {
  width:566px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 27px;
}

section {
  display:block;
}

*, :after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

*, :after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}


.tabPanel {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:160px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

li {
  display:list-item;
}

.listTabs {
    display:block;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Play;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2.5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.11);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2.5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.11);
}

.container {
    height:320px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:24px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto-Regular,serif;
    line-height: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}

.bottomButton {
  height: 61px;
  background-color: #327ca3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Play;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 61px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="outerContainer">
    <section class="container">
      <ul class="tabPanel">
        <li class="listTabs tab0" role="button">
          <span>02</span>
          <span>OCT</span>
        </li>
        <li class="listTabs tab1" role="button">
          <span>01</span>
          <span>OCT</span>
        </li>
        <li class="listTabs tab2" role="button">
          <span>30</span>
          <span>SEP</span>
        </li>
        <li class="listTabs tab3" role="button">
          <span>29</span>
          <span>SEP</span>
        </li>
        <li class="listTabs tab4" role="button">
          <span>28</span>
          <span>SEP</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="contentArea">
        <a class="contentTitle contentTitleSize">Content Area</a>
        <div class="subheading">
          <span>
                   <strong>First</strong>
                   "Second and Third"::after
                   </span>
          <span>more info</span>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <p>lots of details</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="bottomButton">
      Click Me</div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: I tweaked the color logic just a bit to get the desired effect of relational coloring (i.e. close tabs are light, distant tabs are dark). So within the `.each()` call I changed it to this: `d3.select(this).node().className = 'listTabs' + ' ' + 'tab'+tempIndexDifference.` Where `tempIndexDifference` is the distance (measured in tabs) from the active tab to the current tab being evaluated in the `.each()`. I guess I'm really bad at articulating what I want, but your answer got me close enough to find my logic flaws. Thanks again.